# Why two similar model behaves differently in django

Tags: django

I have two similar models but when render them it behaves differently. My first two models are:

```
class Sitting(models.Model):
    sit_date = models.DateField(blank=False,unique=True)
    cut_off_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ballot_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class Circular(models.Model):
     cir_no = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
     sit_start_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
     sit_end_date = models.DateField(blank=False)

    @property
    def ballot(self):
        qs = Sitting.objects.filter(sit_date=self.sit_start_date)
        return qs
```

and in the template:

```
{% for b in c.ballot %}    
    <p>ballot: {{ b.ballot_date }}</p>    
{% endfor %}
```

It gave correct date. But when I use following two models which are nearly same as above it shows nothing:

```
class NewSitting(models.Model):
    sit_date = models.DateField(blank=False, unique=True)
    new_sit_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    cut_off_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ballot_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

def get_new_sit_date(self):
    return self.sit_date

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    if not self.new_sit_date:
        self.new_sit_date = self.get_new_sit_date()
    super(NewSitting, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Circular(models.Model):
    cir_no = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    sit_start_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    sit_end_date = models.DateField(blank=False)

   def newballot(self):
       qs = NewSitting.objects.filter(new_sit_date=self.sit_start_date)
       return qs
```

and In the template:

```
{% for b in c.newballot %}    
    <p>ballot: {{ b.ballot_date }}</p>    
{% endfor %}
```

This template shows nothing. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks @Sayse, Could you please explain why and How I will get that for the second one.

Comment: Just make `ballot_date` as `null=False` if you really want it to be there every time.

Comment: No I don't want it every time. It only be there when only cir_no==1 but I couldn't understand the reason behind of difference

Comment: I solved it by using annotate.(Min('field name'))